# Call Task from Thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

Which task is called this example?

```
new Thread(() => { 
Console.WriteLine("AAA"); 
Task.Delay(5000); 
Console.WriteLine("BBB"); }).Start() ;
```

When we call thread's sleep, we call current thread and what's up with task.Delay if we do not create new task as my example?

In this example I call Task.Delay() without create Task.

Comment: And what research has been done in context of the question. Docs for `Task.Delay` can be found on MSDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Task.Delay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't delay the "current task", it creates a new task that completes after the specified delay. It also doesn't block and will return immediately, unlike `Thread.Sleep`.

Using `Task.Delay` without `await`, `ContinueWith` or other similar methods that either wait for the completion or schedule a continuation is not useful at all.

Comment: As Dirk says. In your case you can call Task.Delay(5000).Wait() to delay the output.